# Highlight Current Navigation Link

Tags: html, css

I have a simple web page navigation bar which is working well. Now I want to style it so that the current page navigation link is a different colour. In this case I want to make the current page navigation link use this colour:

```
color: #00A1DB;
```

I've setup a simplified jsFiddle which shows what I currently have:

http://jsfiddle.net/fmdataweb/BEmXZ/

I've added a class of "current" to the Contacts link to represent that this is the current page. Now I need to modify the CSS so that it changes the colour of the "Contacts" link in the navigation bar to the specified colour.

I've hacked the CSS for the past few hours but can't quite work out the necessary changes to make to get this working. Really appreciate it if someone can show me how to make this happen - learning CSS as I go at the moment.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/BEmXZ/2/

Essential part:

change

```
.sf-menu li.current {
    color: #00A1DB;
}
```

to

```
.sf-menu li.current a {
    color: #00A1DB ! important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you that's exactly what I was after. I knew I was close. Much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Set the styles for class active and hover:

---

Than you need to make the li active, on the server side.
So when you are drawing the menu, you should know which page is loaded and set it to:

```
 <li class="active">Question</li>
 <li>Tags</li>
 <li>Users</li>
```

But if you are changing the content without reloading, you cannot change set the active li element on the server, you need to use javascript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
  .menu{width: 300px; height: 25; font-size: 18px;}
  .menu li{list-style: none; float: left; margin-right: 4px; padding: 5px;}
  .menu li:hover, .menu li.active {
        background-color: #f90;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<ul class="menu">
<li>Item 1</li>
<li class="active">Item 2</li>
<li>Item 3</li>
<li>Item 4</li>
<li>Item 5</li>
<li>Item 6</li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">

var make_button_active = function()
{
  //Get item siblings
  var siblings =($(this).siblings());

  //Remove active class on all buttons
  siblings.each(function (index)
    {
      $(this).removeClass('active');
    }
  )


  //Add the clicked button class
  $(this).addClass('active');
}

//Attach events to menu
$(document).ready(
  function()
  {
    $(".menu li").click(make_button_active);
  }  
)

</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BEmXZ/4/)

Comment: I gave you 1 up,I saw a lot of different systems and your really works!I have a question as my knowledge with javascript is still beginner. I have outside of the ul another link which is the logo of the web. This logo once clicked brings you to the home page. Yes, as its is out of the ul, if I click #home (the logo href) the last link selected of the nav will remain with the class "active". So I was thinking to put an if and else statement in your code to say that, if #home is clicked to removeClass active in the ul where .menu is selected. Could you ilustrate me how to do that?

Comment: call a function on home click and run this line $(".menu li").removeClass('active');

Answer (score 1):

**[See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BEmXZ/5/)**

You can use the jquery `.addClass()` method to add your `current` class to the clicked `li` element and then remove the `current` class using `.removeClass` method for all the other `li` elements.

```
$('#nav ul li').on("click",function(){

  $(this).addClass('current');
var siblings =($(this).siblings());


  siblings.each(function (index)
    {
      $(this).removeClass('current');
    });


    });​
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this by assigning a class to your 'current' button when it is clicked.

You can style the class through CSS like this:

```
.current {
     background-color: #eee;
}
```